# How to Ensure setValue Completes Before Sending 'Enter' Key in Webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, automation, ui-automation, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I have an input field which you can type some values and a dropdown of options populated. it seems [Webdriver.io](https://webdriver.io/) hits the **`Enter`** keyboard key before finishing typing with the **`setValue`** command. I added an arbitrarily await but I want to avoid using this. How can I make sure to wait for the typing to finish in order to move forward?

***This is my code:***

```js
await PO.element.setValue("<value-to-be-typed>")
await browser.pause(3000) // arbitrary wait to allow the dropdown to populate
await browser.keys('Enter')
```

Comment: What is PO.element?

Comment: Page Object, it's reference an element coming from POM, I just wrote PO. But it can be `LoginPage.element`, etc...